# DeleteButton redirecting to show view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm currently developing a React Admin application.

I've added a [DeleteButton](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#toolbar) in the edit view that looks like this:

```
<Edit {...props} undoable={false}>
  <SimpleForm
    toolbar={<InternalUserEditToolbar />}
    validate={handleValidate}
  >
    <InternalUserForm />
  </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

The `DeleteButton` is in the `InternalUserEditToolbar`:

```
<Toolbar {...props} className={classes.toolbar}>
  <SaveButton disabled={props.pristine}/>
  <DeleteButton
    basePath={props.basePath}
    undoable={false}
  />
</Toolbar>
```

The problem is that when I click on the delete button, the user is correctly deleted but I get redirected to the show view of the said user. This results in an error because the user does not exist anymore.

I checked and the `basePath` has the correct value. Even by specifying `redirect="list"` in the props of the `DeleteButton`, the behaviour is still the same.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you using some sort of third party component library? What is a DeleteButton, and why is it redirecting you anywhere?

Comment: I'm not using any third party component library. A DeleteButton is a button provided by React Admin to remove a resource: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#toolbar. It redirects because that's is behaviour.

Comment: I meant I'm not using a third party component library other than React Admin as specified in the question. Sorry about the bad explanation

Comment: why do you set the `basePath` on the `<DeleteButton>`? react-admin does it on its own, you should not need this.

Comment: I was thinking that this behaviour might came from a wrong `basePath` but it's still the same with or without `basePath`.

Comment: Does your resource have a `list` component?

Comment: Yes it does:
```
<Resource
        create={UserInternalCreate}
        edit={UserInternalEdit}
        list={UserInternalList}
        show={UserInternalShow}
        name="admin/users/internal"
        options={{ label: t('@app.common.aside.usersInternal') }}
      />
```

Comment: Then I don't know... My tests with a blank react-admin app don't show the same problem. There mus be something else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `FromWithRedirect`? react-admin docs say that you can provide redirection logic in this component as [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#custom-form-component).